# Detecting null/empty input from user

Tags: asp-classic

How can I check if the user has input a null or empty string in classic-asp? Right now I am have this code.

```
If Request.Form("productId") == "" Then
'my code here
End If
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Classic ASP/VBScript uses one = to check for equality, not two. Another thing you may want to try is

```
If Request.Form("productid") = "" Then
   Code here
End If
```

Comment: Thanks look like its working. If you can give little more help. What is operator for != in classic asp?

Comment: Except that Request.Form("productid") will NEVER be an object, so the test for "Is Nothing" can NEVER be true.  If there is no value passed, simply testing against an empty string is sufficient.

Comment: @Brad, Thanks for the info, it has been a while since I've done classic ASP beyond trivial maintenance. Removed that check from answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a mess.  Here's what I have found ...

(1) To look for existence in the QS, use `if IsEmpty(x)=false` (ie, URL?x)

(2)  To look for a value in the QS, look for `if x <> ""` (ie, URL?x=anything)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
If IsEmpty(Request.Form("inputPhoneNo")) = False Then
    response.Write"<script language=javaScript>alert('Blank Phone Number');</script>"
    response.Write"<script language=javascript>history.back()</script>"
Else

End If
```